# NGINX - How to Serve multiple applications in same base URL - SPA

Tags: nginx, routes, single-page-application, nginx-location

I have two locations in my NGINX setup :

location /APP_B

location /

One for application A (/) and one for Application B. I was able to properly set up so the different subdirectories in the URL would get a proper response, however, I still get a behavior where the browser tries to download all bundle files that my application has from the / directory.

Is there any way in nginx app conf that I can tell that all requests to static files are mapped to a new URL?

Gladly appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. You need to use a `location` block. I'm not sure what your URLs are, however you should end up with something like this:

```
location /APP_B/static/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1111/static;
  proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
}

location /static/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2222/static;
  proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: The problem I have is that when location B is accessed, the request is redirected to the proper container, but then the vendor bundles are downloaded from the original / location. I will try that to see if it works.